# How can I make some part of the vertical ScrollView to be fixed if user is scrolling other horizontal ScrollView ( child of the vertical ScrollView )

Tags: android

I have two `ScrollViews`, horizontal `ScrollView` and vertical `ScrollView`, with horizontal `ScrollView` as a child of vertical I can scroll both vertical and horizontal.

I need some part of the vertical `ScrollView` to be fixed if user is scrolling horizontal.

When user will try to to scroll vertical, he will scroll all the data on the screen, but when he will try to scroll horizontal, only the right part of the screen should be scrolled, but not the whole screen. How can I do it?

I tried to add two childs to my vertical `ScrollView`, but it seems that I can't add more than 1 child to a `ScrollView`, so I can't realize functional I want this way.

I have something like that in my XML. With this layout i can scroll both x and y axis.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10px"
    android:layout_gravity="right">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10px"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button 1" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button 2" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button 3" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button12"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button 4" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button 5" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button 6" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button 7" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button 8" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button8"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button 9" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button9"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button 10" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button10"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button 11" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button111"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button 2" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button21"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button 3" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button31"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button 4" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button121"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button 5" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button41"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Button 6" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Make your horizontalScrollView to be only that part you want to scroll horizontally, not the entire content of the vertical scrollView. You cant add more than one DIRECT child to scrollView, so make another layout that will host your vertical scrolling part and your horizontal scroll

Comment: @Nanoc But how can I synchronize my ScrollViews if I will do it that way? I need to scroll the entire content of the horizontal ScrollView when I scroll vertical SV. But if i will do it the way you said, I will have two completely different ScrollViews ( horizontal and vertical ) without any dependencies on each other. Am i right?

It's just like a table with fixed column of names in the left. When you scroll it to the right, the names will still be fixed in the left of the table, but other columns of the table will change. That's what i'm need

Comment: The horizontal scrollView will still be inside the ScrollView, it should be still scrolling vertically, what dependencies on each other are you saying??

Comment: @Nanoc Got you now. It's working. Not as precisely as I wanted, because it's will be hard to do some things I want with this solution, but anyway it's the right solution of the question I asked. If you write an answer I will mark it as correct answer.

Comment: Nesting scrollViews is usually a bad thing to do.

Comment: @Nanoc I have already understood this, I think that I will try to find a way to solve the problem using a RecyclerView and a CustomLayoutManager, but anyway your solution is correct.